# How can download WSO2AM docker image 4.1.0?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wso2, wso2-api-manager

There is a bug in the latest version of WSO2AM when the soap API transform to rest.
Now I want to use the 4.1.0 version. But its docker image has been removed from https://hub.docker.com/

How can I get this docker file?

docker image file 4.1.0

Comment: There seems to be an alpine image with 4.1.0 https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2am/wso2am/tags or am I looking at the wrong WSO2AM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public Docker images for newer products (APIM 4.1.0 or newer) are no longer available. It is recommended to build your own Docker image by following the steps in [1] if you are using the Open Source version of the product.

If you have a WSO2 subscription, you can get APIM 4.1.0 docker image from the WSO2 private docker registry.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/4.1.x/dockerfiles/ubuntu/apim